# Inserting nodes before a certain node in Doubly Linked List

Tags: java, list, insert, doubly-linked-list

I have created Doubly Linked List as below

```
8 <-> 2 <-> 12
```

I have to insert following nodes before node "2"

Nodes to insert -(8,22,23,15)

Node "8" is already present before node "2", In this case i don't want to insert node "8" again. Is there any way to check "node to insert" is already present before the node or not?

I want final DLL as `8 <-> 22 <-> 23 <-> 15 <-> 2 <-> 12`

Answer (score 0):

However, if you don't want to repeat series:

Current List:

> 1 ↔ 2 ↔ 3

**Insert before 3:** (1, 2, 4)

Result wanted:

> 1 ↔ 2 ↔ 4 ↔ 3

It gets a little bit more complicated, but not much.

**First**, check if the node before the one you use as *base* matches any of your *to introduce* nodes. Starting for the last one (so you get always the longest series repeated, and avoid it).

**If one matches** check if the rest of the serie before it matches too. If it does, start from the next (or add none, if it's the last); if it doesn't, go back to **First** step.

**Second and last** After you have selected the next node to add (if you didn't match any on **First**, just start on the first one) just add them before the *base*.

**This is pseudocode, since I don't know your exact implementation:**

Considering:

```
int[] toAdd = {1, 2, 4};
```

For example, you can use recursivity:

```
main {
    int from = 0;
    for (int i = toAdd.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (checkSerie(toAdd, i, base) {
            from = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    // And add:
    for (int i = from; i < toAdd.length; i++) {
        addBefore(3, toAdd[i]); // Your add method.
    }
}

private boolean checkSerie (int[] toAdd, int index, Node base){
    Node prev = base.prev;
    if (index < 0) {
        return true;
    }

    if (toAdd[index] != prev) {
        return false;
    }

    return checkSeriei (toAdd, index - 1, prev);
}
```

**Note:** I haven't tested this, it might be buggy (maybe some wrong -1 or stuff like that), but should be enough to help you get the idea.

Comment: And if you meant something else, just comment it and I will edit or make a new answer.

Comment: I want to do option 2.. If u give code means it will helpful for me.

Comment: Check the edit, It's not good code (the == and != for example wouldn't work, since you are comparing ints and objects, you need to implement that) and it's not tested, but I hope it helps you understand.

If it does, remember to mark it as answered.